# Google visualization query response format

Tags: json, google-visualization

I have a [sample spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdDBKYUhRdVVhb2xGel91c2FkV1daYkE#gid=0) and we can get the query response json format by publishing the sheet [which is given here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdDBKYUhRdVVhb2xGel91c2FkV1daYkE#gid=0). Here in json format, what is the legends "c", "v", "p" etc stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More details [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#jsondatatable) :

```
c : cells  (edited from @asgallant comment)
v : value
f : formatted value
p : property
```

Comment: f in `{"v":2.0,"f":"2"}`?

Comment: "c" is the array of cells in row of data, not a column.  "f" is the formatted value of a cell.